# How do I reliably determine if parent template item empty or not in jquery template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery templates to build a tree. It works very well so far, but I came across an issue when trying to determine if an item is at the root level or not.

I use a template similar to that of render tree items:

```
<script id="tree-row-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<li>
    <div class="row ${NodeType}">
        <a href="#">${Name}</a>
    </div>
    {{if expanded}}
        <ul>
            {{tmpl($data.chidren || []) "#tree-row-tmpl"}}
        </ul>
    {{/if}}
</li>
</script>
```

Now in the link `click` handler I try to determine root node using:

```
if($.tmplItem(this).parent)
```

It turned out the root `tmplItem.parent` is not null (as I expected), but contains an object with two properties: `{data:{}, key:0}`.
I see that I can check `item.parent.parent` or one of the properties which exist in regular `tmplItem` and missing in the root object. But this seems like a kind of hack for me - I'd prefer finding an "official" way of verifying a `tmplItem` whether it's empty or valid.